# How to create tiles from c# code

Tags: gdal, .net

I need to create tiles directly from c# code. The input file is in *.tif format. Is there a way to do this simply? I tried GDAL, but I found it complicated, I don't understand how to cut tiff into tiles (I'm novice in GIS :-(). Anyone can help me with logic how to create tiles for particular zoom level through GDAL? Probably, another way exists to do this task?

P.S. Unfortunately, using of gdal2tiles isn't suitable for me.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?